# What is the probability of a monkey favoring red to blue and yellow?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

These weird monkeys favors the types of berries: red, yellow and blue ones. However, not all monkeys are created equally. The probability of a monkey favoring red to blue and yellow - Hint: [$RYB$, $RBY$, $BRY$, $BYR$, $YRB$, $YBR$]. The trick here is that the monkey prefers red over blue, but you are not sure that she prefers yellow to red or blue.

Imagine for a moment that monkeys eat only three types of berries — blue, red, and yellow — and that monkeys have preferences towards certain berries. For example, some believe red berries are best, followed by blue, then yellow ($R \gt B \gt Y$). The monkeys' preferences are strict: there are no ties, leaving us with only six possible orderings of the berries. All preferences are equally likely: one sixth of the monkey population feels that $R \gt B \gt Y$; another sixth believes instead that $R \gt Y \gt B$.

You meet a random monkey and give her a choice between a red and a blue berry. She picks red. Now you offer red or yellow. Given her earlier choice, what is the probability she will again choose red?

**Edit:** This is not a homework question, so please do not report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monkey picks red over blue, so it either belongs to RYB, RBY or YRB. If all events are equally likely, the probability that the monkey will prefer red over yellow equals:

$$\frac{P[RYB] + P[RBY]}{P[RYB] + P[RBY] + P[YRB]} = \frac{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: thanks  a lot for help